# defining parameter to class in python

Tags: python, class, parameters

Here is the code and the error that I am getting when I run the program . Can anyone explain what mistake I am doing? Also is it good to call a function of a class in the constructor like I did?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy

class move_turtlebot(message):
    def __init__(self):
          self.pub=rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)
          self.vel=Twist()
          rospy.loginfo("initiated!!")
         self.move(message)
    def move(self,message):
          if message=="STOP":
              rospy.loginfo("inside stop")
              self.vel=Twist()
              self.pub.publish(vel)
          elif message=="LEFT":
        #rest of code continues 
if __name__=="__main__":

   rospy.init_node('move_turtlebot')
   rospy.loginfo("here!")

   while not rospy.is_shutdown():
       ahead=move_turtlebot("FORWARD")
```

The error is:NameError: name 'message' is not defined at the line of defining class

Comment: In your `__init__` method `message` has not yet been defined. Also `elif` is not indented correctly

Comment: Your class `move_turtlebot` inherits from `message` but this class is not defined/imported

Comment: I created an object of class "ahead=move_turtlebot("FORWARD"), the message variable is a string "FORWARD", isn't this sufficient. What does defining/importing class mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class move_turtlebot(message): # this means inheritance from a class message which u dont have or didnt define
```

For a class to have parameters they can be defined at the constructor like this (although there are variations) :

```
class move_turtlebot:
    def __init__(self,message):
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Class definition you are using message:

class move_turtlebot(**message**): <--- HERE

you don't have message defined, if you want to use message in your consructor add it to your `__init__` function like so:

```py
def __init__(self, message)
```

also I noted that the last line in your init function uses different indentation, if it is the same at your code, change it as well.

Hope it helps